# Paypal geteway Internal Error (#10001: Internal Error)

Tags: magento-1.8, paypal-express

This is Debug log dump.
But I have no idea what's going on.

Test in paypal sandbox mode.
 
Check out with Paypal express.

```
2014-05-01T06:30:17+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [url] => https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
    [ManagePendingTransactionStatus] => Array
        (
            [TRANSACTIONID] => 4GB13868J7284553K
            [ACTION] => Accept
            [METHOD] => ManagePendingTransactionStatus
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [USER] => ****
            [PWD] => ****
            [SIGNATURE] => ****
            [BUTTONSOURCE] => Varien_Cart_EC
        )

    [response] => Array
        (
            [TRANSACTIONID] => 4GB13868J7284553K
            [STATUS] => The Status of the transaction after running the your action (accept/deny) is:Unable To Determine
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-05-01T06:30:11Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => c38b1544405a1
            [ACK] => Failure
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [BUILD] => 10800277
            [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10001
            [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
            [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
            [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
        )

    [__pid] => 553023
)
```

exception.log

```
2014-04-30T06:08:43+00:00 ERR (3): 
    exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'PayPal NVP gateway errors: Internal Error (#10001: Internal Error). Correlation ID: e472a9b1d2146. Version: 72.0.' in /home/sokietec/public_html/app/Mage.php:580
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/sokietec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(1050): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'PayPal NVP gate...')
    #1 /home/sokietec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(1011): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->_handleCallErrors(Array)
    #2 /home/sokietec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(773): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->call('ManagePendingTr...', Array)
    #3 /home/sokietec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Pro.php(311): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->callManagePendingTransactionStatus()
    #4 /home/sokietec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express.php(406): Mage_Paypal_Model_Pro->reviewPayment(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), 'accept')
    #5 /home/sokietec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(932): Mage_Paypal_Model_Express->acceptPayment(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment))
    #6 /home/sokietec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(896): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->registerPaymentReviewAction('accept', true)
    #7 /home/sokietec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(240): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->accept()
    #8 /home/sokietec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->reviewPaymentAction()
    #9 /home/sokietec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reviewPayment')
    #10 /home/sokietec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #11 /home/sokietec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #12 /home/sokietec/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #13 /home/sokietec/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #14 {main}
```

Comment: I'm getting the exact same problem with Magento 1.7.0.2, very infuriating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after doing some searching there appears to be a couple of things you can try:

1. Those who are getting #10001: Internal Error error, please check ”Allowed Currencies” settings from System >> Configuration >> GENERAL >> Currency Setup. The currency in which you are making payment must be selected there,
2. Go back in your PayPal account profile then IPN and select “accept express checkout” and and wait for few hours and test it again,
3. Validate your credentials and try again,

Answer (score 1):

My very similar issue had been fixed by creating one new Paypal merchant test account with same currency to my Magento store.

Paypal default's merchant account is US currency, but my Magento store base currency is AU. This has caused the issue: the order had been paid, but its status has been pending for this currency conflict.

Mostly, in my opinion, this kind of errors should be caused by our configuration on Magento or Paypal side, like the Payment Review option has been turned on (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298117/paypal-ipn-always-return-payment-status-pending-on-sandbox)

Hopefully, my experience can save u more time.

PayPal Express Log

```
2014-12-12T01:51:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [url] => https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
    [GetTransactionDetails] => Array
        (
            [TRANSACTIONID] => 15Y48062WM0910211
            [METHOD] => GetTransactionDetails
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [USER] => ****
            [PWD] => ****
            [SIGNATURE] => ****
            [BUTTONSOURCE] => OneStepCheckout_SI_MagentoCE
        )

    [response] => Array
        (
            [RECEIVEREMAIL] => john.au-facilitator@gmail.com
            [RECEIVERID] => VQ37QYGD3SFPW
            [EMAIL] => john.yin.au-buyer@gmail.com
            [PAYERID] => LXDH2RT89NRAS
            [PAYERSTATUS] => verified
            [COUNTRYCODE] => US
            [SHIPTONAME] => john h
            [SHIPTOSTREET] => 33
            [SHIPTOSTREET2] => esdfd re
            [SHIPTOCITY] => ddw
            [SHIPTOSTATE] => AL
            [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => AU
            [SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => Australia
            [SHIPTOZIP] => 34343
            [ADDRESSOWNER] => PayPal
            [ADDRESSSTATUS] => Confirmed
            [INVNUM] => 100000036
            [SALESTAX] => 0.00
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-12-12T01:51:34Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => 2ef746f5f1a77
            [ACK] => Success
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [BUILD] => 14077178
            [FIRSTNAME] => Test
            [LASTNAME] => Buyer
            [TRANSACTIONID] => 15Y48062WM0910211
            [TRANSACTIONTYPE] => cart
            [PAYMENTTYPE] => instant
            [ORDERTIME] => 2014-12-12T01:50:39Z
            [AMT] => 44.00
            [TAXAMT] => 0.00
            [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
            [HANDLINGAMT] => 0.00
            [CURRENCYCODE] => AUD
            [PAYMENTSTATUS] => Pending
            [PENDINGREASON] => multicurrency
            [REASONCODE] => None
            [PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY] => Eligible
            [PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE] => ItemNotReceivedEligible,UnauthorizedPaymentEligible
            [L_NAME0] => color swatch te
            [L_NUMBER0] => ZP-D3241-WHITE-L
            [L_QTY0] => 1
            [L_TAXAMT0] => 0.00
            [L_SHIPPINGAMT0] => 0.00
            [L_HANDLINGAMT0] => 0.00
            [L_CURRENCYCODE0] => AUD
            [L_AMT0] => 44.00
        )

    [__pid] => 30696
)
```

The System Exception Log

```
2014-12-12T01:41:41+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'PayPal NVP gateway errors: Array Correlation ID: 18c04485dd86d. Version: 72.0.' in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php:1062
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(1008): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->_handleCallErrors(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(616): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->call('SetExpressCheck...', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php(381): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->callSetExpressCheckout()
#3 /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php(108): Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout->start('http://54.79.66...', 'http://54.79.66...', false)
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract->startAction()
#5 /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('start')
#6 /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /var/www/html/magento2/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /var/www/html/magento2/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created new merchant and buyer accounts and used them (had different countries before) which solved that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833313/paypal-sandbox-doexpresscheckoutpayment-10001-internal-error/43031119#43031119